# Runtime error 91 when pulling Google Translate Output

Tags: html, excel, vba, getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyclassname

I'm making a VBA function which will translate text to another language by pulling the translated text from Google Translate using "getelementsByClassName".  I'm pulling the correct information, and aside from an error popping up, the code works.  However, I'm running into

> runtime error 91 - Obj var or with block var not set

once the code reaches
`x = element.Item(0).innerText` in the code below.  Once I click debug and continue the script, the code does exactly as I expect, and assigns the correct translation as a string to the temporary variable I've used, `x`.

Anyone know why this error is popping up and why it doesn't seem to matter once I continue the script?  If there's a different version of `application.DisplayAlerts` that I can throw around this line to make the error not show up that would suffice as well.

I've just used the google translate webpage for translating "Hello World" to spanish for simplicity here.

```
Public Sub Translate()

Dim page As String
page = "https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=es&text=Hello%20world"

Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
IE.navigate page

'Wait til webpage is fully loaded
Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Application.StatusBar = "Loading translation..."
    DoEvents
Loop

Dim element As IHTMLElementCollection
Set element = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("result-shield-container tlid-copy-target")

Dim x As String
x = element.Item(0).innerText
MsgBox x

End Sub
```

UPDATE

Problem ended up being a timing issue where `getElementsByClassName` was being run before IE was fully loaded.  Tried adding `Or IE.Busy` and every combination of `.Busy` and `.readyState` that I could think of while still coming into the problem.  Using a `Sleep` routine worked for a while, however successive iterations would run into the same error.  Found a working method from one article which used the following method, which uses the first `while` to ensure the next `until` is not skipped.

```
   Do While .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
   Do Until .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
   Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
   Do Until .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
```

Comment: I know this wont help, but for what it's worth, I tried your code and it works fine with no errors for me.

Comment: Any information is good information to me.  Since it worked for you, I inserted a new module and copied in the code - worked without showing the error popup.  But any subsequent runs after that show the error.  Did the same thing again and copied the code into a new module, same results.  So I assume something isn't resetting correctly at the end of the code, but I don't know enough about how vba to tell.

Comment: Come to think of it... I did add: `IE.Quit` and then `Set IE = Nothing` after the `MsgBox` - try adding those lines?

Comment: Your code creates an additional instance of IE each time you run it, so Without the `.Quit` part, those instances remain open and are invisible because you never set their visibility property to true... They would show up in the Task Manager tho if you looked there. I added those lines just because it made sense to me to clean up the mess it made each time I ran it, and that might explain why it worked the first time but not thereafter.

Comment: Saw your comment and thought, of course that's the issue, so I did exactly what you suggested.  Unfortunately, that wasn't the issue (though definitely necessary because I had about 32 IE applications open when I looked on task manager)

But did notice the code worked every time when I had a breakpoint at ```
x = element.Item(0).innerText``` and continued the code manually.  After that, just added a simple ```Sleep 100``` and the code works perfectly almost all the time now.  So I guess I'm having timing issues with the  ```getElementsByClassName``` part of the code.